# How to return all objects in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, flash, flowplayer, caption

I have a variable that is created by Flowplayer and available via javascript.  If I write the variable to the page directly it just returns 'object Object' so I am assuming this is an array.  If I don't know the names of any of the objects inside the array, how can I parse out the data inside?

I know I am missing something really fundamental here, but I don't think I have ever had to get data from an array not knowing what it contains.

Notes:

- What I am trying to do is get the onCuePoint caption data embedded
  into an RTMP video stream
- .valueOf() returns the same thing
- Here is the code I am using that returns 'object Object':

`streamCallbacks: ['onFI'],

    clip:`

```
{
    live:true,          
    provider: 'rtmp',
    autoPlay: true,
    url:'test1',
    onFI:function(clip, info)
    {
        document.getElementById("onFI").innerHTML += "Data: " + info;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through your array and get the results one by one, replace your onFI function with this :

```
onFI:function(clip, info)
{
    var data = "";

    // For each value in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
    {
         // Add it to the data string (each record will be separated by a space)
         data += info[i] + ' ';
    }

    document.getElementById("onFI").innerHTML += "Data: " + data;
}
```

Comment: The last line just adds a space at the end of the data string(which will be without space between the elements).

Comment: Just a last thing :P if `data` is not initialized and supposing `info` is a list of strings you will have `data == "undefined"+info[1]+...;`, you should initialize `data` to `""`. Otherwise, if info is a list of number and you initialize it to a string then you will get not a list of numbers but a string containing info numbers

Comment: Yes, now it should be okay. Anyway, for the future, whem you don't know anything about the type of the data, if you know that the array will be homogeneous you can initialize `data` to `array[0]` and then loop through the array starting from 1.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. Do users with 1 reputation ever vote on a best answer, or they just take off with the solution never to be seen again? This has happened on pretty much all my answers, quite discouraging.

Comment: They often forget to accept an answer unfortunately, but in my opinion the important thing is to help the OP. Personally I don't mind, I'm here to help people, not to get reputation :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Been in meetings all day but hoping to get online tonight/tomorrow AM and review/test the solutions. I might be a new stackoverflow member but I'm not new to the internet- promise I will mark an answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I was making this way more complex in my head than I needed to.  This gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are asking is how you iterate over the contents of an array, you can do so in plain javascript like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // arr[i] is each item of the array
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Just because something is of type Object does not necessarily mean that it's an array.  It could also just be a plain object with various properties on it.  If you look at the `info` argument in either the debugger or with `console.log(info)`, you should be able to see what it is.

Comment: If the info variable is not an array, its content can be shown with: `var str=''; for (var p in info) { str += p + '=' + info[p] + '<br/>'; } document.getElementById("onFI").innerHTML += "Data: " + str;` but better is to view to with `console.log(info)` as jfriend suggests. (Firefox Ctrl+Shift+k or Chrome Ctrl+j)

Comment: Thanks! Marked the other one as the answer b/c it looked like he needed the rep points more, but this also helped.  @Stano thanks for your addition- it was very helpful